# Merge Two Sorted Lists - LeetCode (Python)

Tags: python

Why Leetcode is forcing us to mold our solution into a frame that does not make sense (at least to me)?

For the Merge two Sorted list question (here: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/) this is the framework given as default:

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
```

I don't understand why we should use a class here? I think I solved the question using the below algorithm:

```py
def mergeTwoLists(list1, list2):

    if len(list1) == 0 or len(list2) == 0:
        ans = list1 + list2
    elif list1[-1] < list2[0]:
        ans = list1.extend(list2)
    elif list2[-1] < list1[0]:
        ans = list2.extend(list1)
    else:

        i = len(list1) - 1
        j = -1

        for item in list2:
            for x in range(i, j, -1):

                if item >= list1[x]:
                    list1.insert(x+1,item)
                    i += 1
                    j = x 
                    ans = list1
                    break
                
                
    return ans
```

But when I submit my answer it gives the below non sensical error:

```
Runtime Error Message:
NameError: name 'Solution' is not defined
    ret = Solution().mergeTwoLists(param_1, param_2)
Line 50 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 61 in <module> (Solution.py)
Last executed input:
[1,2,4]
[1,3,4]
```

which I don't get on my machine! On my local system the code works perfectly. Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: I think the question mentions "Linked List". What you are using as a solution is assuming it as a normal python list.

Comment: you have to use linked list to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Solution class is present due to a driver code that runs runs first and redirects the execution to start from the class Solution.